# How to make the origin marker (GM API DirectionService) move slowly to the updated position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I have a RoR project where I get JSON coordinates for two objects, **mission** and **truck** .

I use those coordinates to draw a route between them, via Google Maps API DirectionService.

While **mission's** coordinates are static, **truck's** aren't, so using AJAX, I'm requesting them every 10 seconds.

Atm, truck's marker "jumps" to its new position, creating an ugly effect.

What I want to accomplish is, every time truck's coordinates are updating, truck's marker should slowly slide to its new position.

Any ideas on how to do this, would be really appreciated!

Here's my js file:

```
$(document).on('page:change', function() {
  //gets new truck position every 10 seconds
  var intervalId = setInterval(getNewTruckPosition, 10000);

  // initial truck coordinates
  newTruckLatLng = {lat: 41.85, lng: -87.65};

  // mission coordinates(directionService destination -> static)
  missionLatLng = {lat: 40.771, lng: -73.974};
  drawMapData();

  function getNewTruckPosition() {
    $.ajax({
      ....
      success: function(data) {

        //gets new coordinates for truck
        newTruckLat = "new-value-from-json";
        newTruckLong = "new-value-from-json";
        newTruckLatLng = {lat: newTruckLat, lng: newTruckLong};

        //calculates and draws new route every time truck coordinates are updated
        drawMapData();
      }
    });
  }
  initMap();
});
function drawMapData() {

 ##########ISSUE I'M TRYING TO SOLVE#############

  //draws a new marker for the truck, deleting the last one ---> 
  //this results in a truck marker jumping effect
  //what I would like to achieve is the truck marker 
  //sliding to its new position, not jumping

  if (typeof newTruckLat != 'undefined') {
    function makeMarker() {
      if (typeof newMarker != 'undefined') {
        newMarker.setMap(null);
      }
      newMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        //value received from JSON
        position: newTruckLatLng,
        map: map,
        title: "Truck's Position"
      });
    }
  }


  //***********ROUTING****************//

  directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

  directionsDisplay.setOptions(
  {
    suppressInfoWindow: true,
    suppressMarkers: true,
    polylineOptions: {
      strokeColor: "#1A239A",
      strokeOpacity: 0.9 ,
      strokeWeight: 5
     }
   });

  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

  calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);

  function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
    directionsService.route({

      //value received from JSON

      origin: newTruckLatLng,
      destination: missionLatLng,
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    }, function(response, status) {
      if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        makeMarker();
      } else {
        window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
      }
    });
  }
//***********Finished ROUTING****************//

}

function initMap() {

  isDraggable = $(document).width() > 480 ? true : false;

  if (typeof truckLat != 'undefined') {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 12,
      draggable: isDraggable,
      scrollwheel: false,
      disableDefaultUI: true
    });
  }

  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: missionLatLng,
    map: map,
    title: "Mission's Position"
  });

  newMarker = new google.maps.Marker({

    //initial value {newTruckLatLng = {lat: 41.85, lng: -87.65}}
    position: newTruckLatLng,
    map: map,
    title: "Truck's Position"
  });

  markers = [marker, newMarker];
  bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
   bounds.extend(markers[i].getPosition());
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue you are trying to solve.

Comment: Edited my question with more comments on the issue I'm having. Please do let me know if it's clear enough or should I add additional information. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve my issue.

HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/v3_epoly.js"></script>

<div id="map"></div>
```

JS:

```
initialTruckLatLng = {lat: 48.8479, lng: 2.48678};
newTruckLatLng = {lat: 48.8479, lng: 2.5914};
missionLatLng = {lat: 48.8479, lng: 2.6514};


var map;
var directionDisplay;
var directionsService;
var stepDisplay;
var markerArray = [];
var position;
var marker = null;
var polyline = null;
var speed = 0.000005, wait = 1;
var infowindow = null;

var myPano;
var panoClient;
var nextPanoId;
var timerHandle = null;

function createMarker(latlng) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    map: map
  });
  return marker;
}

function initialize() {
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ 
    size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)
  });
    // Instantiate a directions service.
  directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

  // Create a map and center it on mission.
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: missionLatLng,
    zoom: 12,
    scrollwheel: false,
    disableDefaultUI: true
  });

  // Create a renderer for directions and bind it to the map.
  var rendererOptions = {
    map: map
  }
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);

  // Instantiate an info window to hold step text.
  stepDisplay = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [],
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeWeight: 3
  });

  missionMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: missionLatLng,
    map: map,
    title: 'label'
  });
  marker = createMarker(initialTruckLatLng);
  markers = [marker, missionMarker];
  bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
   bounds.extend(markers[i].getPosition());
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}

var steps = []

function calcRoute(){

  if (timerHandle) { clearTimeout(timerHandle); }
  if (marker) { marker.setMap(null);}
  polyline.setMap(null);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(null);
  polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [],
    strokeColor: '#1A239A',
    strokeOpacity: 0.9 ,
    strokeWeight: 5
  });

  // Create a renderer for directions and bind it to the map.
  var rendererOptions = {
    map: map
  }

  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);

  var start = initialTruckLatLng;
  var end = newTruckLatLng;
  var travelMode = google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING

  var request = {
    origin: start,
    destination: end,
    travelMode: travelMode
  };

  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK){
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);

      var route = response.routes[0];
      startLocation = new Object();
      endLocation = new Object();

      // For each route, display summary information.
      var path = response.routes[0].overview_path;
      var legs = response.routes[0].legs;
      for (i=0;i<legs.length;i++) {
        if (i == 0) { 
          startLocation.latlng = legs[i].start_location;
          startLocation.address = legs[i].start_address;
          // marker = google.maps.Marker({map:map,position: startLocation.latlng});
          marker = createMarker(legs[i].start_location);
        }
        endLocation.latlng = legs[i].end_location;
        endLocation.address = legs[i].end_address;
        var steps = legs[i].steps;
        for (j=0;j<steps.length;j++) {
          var nextSegment = steps[j].path;
          for (k=0;k<nextSegment.length;k++) {
            polyline.getPath().push(nextSegment[k]);
            bounds.extend(nextSegment[k]);
          }
        }
      }

      polyline.setMap(map);
      startAnimation();
    }
  });

  // create a new route between the actual truck position and mission position
  directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

  directionsDisplay.setOptions(
  {
    suppressInfoWindow: true,
    preserveViewport: true,
    polylineOptions: {
      strokeColor: "#1A239A",
      strokeOpacity: 0.9 ,
      strokeWeight: 5
     }
   });

  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

  calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);

  function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
    directionsService.route({
      origin: newTruckLatLng,
      destination: missionLatLng,
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    }, function(response, status) {
      if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      } else {
        window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
      }
    });
  }    
}

var step = 50; // 5; // metres
var tick = 100; // milliseconds
var eol;
var k=0;
var stepnum=0;
var speed = "";
var lastVertex = 1;

//=============== animation functions ======================

function animate(d) {
  if (d >= eol) {
    polyline.setMap(null);
  }

  if (d>eol) {
    marker.setPosition(endLocation.latlng);
    return;
  }
  markers = [marker, missionMarker];
  bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
   bounds.extend(markers[i].getPosition());
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);

  var p = polyline.GetPointAtDistance(d);
  marker.setPosition(p);

  timerHandle = setTimeout("animate("+(d+step)+")", tick);
}


function startAnimation() {
  eol=polyline.Distance();
  setTimeout("animate(50)",2000);  // Allow time for the initial map display
}


//=============== ~animation functions =====================
```